# import sharepoint 2010 list data in json format using javascript (IE8)

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-server, rest, internet-explorer

i have a sharepoint list already created and populated from an excel file. How would i go about pulling data from sharepoint to a json object in my javascript program.

Another requirement is that the method be compliant with IE8 as that is the version currently running on all the computers that are to access it. 
the sharepoint list has 13 columns with around 100 rows. So it doesnt need much computational power.

i seem to have seen a few examples using rest queries but they were either too complex or dint seem to work in ie8 and sharepoint 2010

Sorry if the question is too simple, i just started using sharepoint and seem to be confused by the sheer amount of documentation involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work fine. Haven't tested in IE8 but I think it'll work.

```
function getData(siteurl) {
var endpoint = siteurl +"/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ListName";
$.ajax({
url: endpoint,
method: "GET",
headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
    "Content-Type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
},
success: function (data) {
     //data variable will have list json data
},
error: function (error) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
}
});
}
```

Comment: I tried the above code but what i seem to be getting in the console is html data of the page rather than the list items in json format. I am guessing this is due to the url being given in a wrong manner. This is how i have given it - http://sharepointsite.com/sites/sharepoint/test/Lists/SharepointList/AllItems.aspx
i even tried -
http://sharepointsite.com/sites/sharepoint/test/Lists/SharepointList

Comment: Yes, that is the wrong format. Endpoint URL must be `http://sharepointsite.com/sites/sharepoint/test/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/SharePointList`. This will query the listdata.svc web service and get you the list data.

Comment: Right i input the link as you suggested but now i am neither getting any data in the console nor am i getting an error message. The console is clean. The data is not displaying either. How to troubleshoot this ?

--edit--
Hmm so after a minute i seem to be getting an error that says invalid argument and the location of this error is in the eval code.

Comment: To check if the URL is correct, simply copy/paste the URL in the address bar. If data is displayed in the browser in XML format, URL is correct. If the URL is correct, you'll be able to retrieve it using JS.

Comment: I tried the link as you said but on pasting it in the browser it just says 404 not found which must mean the url is wrong in some manner. Maybe this will help - In the sherepoint site when i open the list the link is like this : http://sharepointsite.com/sites/sharepoint/test/Lists/sharepointList/allitems.aspx
This link is what displays all the items of the list to me in sharepoint .

Comment: Ideally the link format is: http://siteurl/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/listName. From your URL, siteurl would be sharepointsite.com/sites/sharepoint/test. ListName would be sharepointList. Ensure that spelling is correct.

Comment: That link is what i tried once you gave me the format but that yields the same error 404 page. Now i am really stumped. I have tried almost all combinations of the link to no success. Any idea how i could get to the root of this link problem ?

Comment: another point is that the link to page that displays all the lists in the site is given by - http://sharepointsite.com/sites/sharepoint/test/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx.

Comment: Try entering till listdata.svc. siteurl/listdata.svc

Comment: Hurrah.thanks for the link. i opened it and found out the list name is automatically corrected to capitalise the first letter so my mistake was not capitalizing the first letter of the list name in the link.  

But i seem to have run into another problem. the JSON data is not getting read properly. when i dump it to the log i get [object object] . how do i get the correct form of the json variable?

Comment: If you view the log in chrome, you'll be able to expand the object. Or else, you can iterate over the object and write its properties. Google for more info.

Comment: Got it. just needed to use the right nesting variable. Thank you for your curt and quick replies. Really made a difference.